# How to install jdt.core in eclipse locally?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm needing to install the eclipse JDT.Core plugin locally (eg download the file with site.xml etc), as opposed to installing it remotely due to the horrible firewall at work.
Can anyone suggest where to download it so i can do the local install?
Thanks

Comment: In the end, i downloaded JDT from the eclipse site, unzipped it's plugins and features folders into my eclipse distribution, and started eclipse with a '-clean' so it picked it up. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I ever saw an installation of jdt.core, since it is included in most of the eclipse distros (either [Eclipse 3.5 Galileo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) or [Eclipse 3.6 Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/m6))

That being said, the [jdt core](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php) update site is part of the [global Eclipse update sites](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites), and I don't think you can easily download just the jdt.core part.

The easiest way would still be to download a full distro with JDT already included in it.

Comment: The problem is that we're using a bastardised version of eclipse that has been customised for a particular vendor. Sounds like we're screwed.

Comment: In the end, i downloaded JDT from the eclipse site, unzipped it's plugins and features folders into my eclipse distribution, and started eclipse with a '-clean' so it picked it up. Worked a charm.

Comment: The other problem is that the "default" distro is now bloated to an insane 200 MB (almost half of which is crud, unrelated to Java development). The only way to get it is to skip the "default", download "eclipse-platform", and then manually install the stuff that used to be "default". Sigh. Looking forwards to going back to IntelliJ as soon as this project is over...

Answer (score 10):

I assume you are using Aptana, well like VonC said I don't know if there is a JDT core download site link but I personally did something else that worked for me.

on eclipse or aptana

1. Go to "Help", then go to "Install New Software", and the install dialog pops up.
2. Click on the "Available Software Sites" link on the install dialog.
3. Check on or copy "Eclipse Helios Update Site    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios Enabled" or just skip step 2 and copy and paste this link "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios"
4. Add it and it gives your a list of softwares, go to "Programming Languages" and choose "Eclipse Java Development Tool"

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks, google landed me on this page, and it was of immense help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Help > Install new software and add 
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/[your release e.g. indigo]

Under the Programming Languages section, select Eclipse Java Development Tools.

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Find the jdt jar from the following location.

http://www.findjar.com/jar/eclipse/jars/jdtcore-3.0.1.jar.html

Just add this to your project library.

Enjoy !!!!