# can i import java project in c++ eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a C/C++ Eclipse. I want to import java project into my C/C++ Eclipse for my development purpose. I have tried importing. But it is not opening as a java file. It is showing the java files as Just text files?

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ version of Eclipse doesn't recognize Java syntax and Java source files. If you want to code in Java, you should [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1) the Java version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Java development tools (JDT). You shall check the version of your Eclipse C/C++ first, then install the same version JDT. 
Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701354 for install via update site.
You can also [download](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) **JDT Runtime Binary** for offline install.