# How to install eclipse java development tool package in eclipse offline

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, offline

I am trying to install Java development too in eclipse but it is taking tooooo long.
[image]
 Currently there is only CDT installed in my eclipse. I am using Linux mint 18.2 XFCE and opendjk 8 and oracle jkd 9. Whenever I try to install java development tool,it takes too Long.I can see that It is downloading at the speed of 10 to 2 kbps.(i am prety sure that My net is Not this much slow)So I want to download the eclipse java development tool manually from Firefox and then install it offline. how can I do this ?? I am new to eclipse and java.

Comment: Download your `.ZIP` file package/plugin, and then follow the steps at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482554/how-to-install-plugin-for-eclipse-from-zip  I'd recommend the auto-install option.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for reply . But I don't know How to download package ? I am Noob to eclipse and these java things.

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550755/how-to-install-jdt-core-in-eclipse-locally  Your distro should have it. Perhaps you should re-download and reinstall Eclipse.  Seems like it's not easily accessed as a standalone installation

Answer (score 0):

Open [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) then download manualy the version you need. Then via the terminal you should be able to install it.